# Can realm be used like MySQL

Tags: mysql, realm

Is realm just for storing locally and when the app is deleted the data disappears to or can you use it for syncing data across all devices through a server?

Comment: Please try to explain your purpose better, May be you will get solutions to what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

> Is realm just for storing locally and when the app is deleted the data disappears too

Realm is a local database (which works on mobile devices only - iOS and Android).

> or can you use it for syncing data across all devices through a server?

You can! It's a whole new thing. Using the Realm Object Server, released today (2016-09-28) as part of the Realm Mobile Platform.

Comment: do you knot any good and popular databasing libraries for IOS?

Comment: Core Data and Realm. o-o

Comment: Ones that can sync across multiple devices? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: I'm an android developer and not an iOS developer, so I don't know anything beyond that :P

Comment: With iOS you can try the official CoreData support for CloudKit. I've never used it before (because Realm just rocks) but I know it's getting some improvements and bug fixes since the initial launch.

Comment: Realm just announced an official solution for syncing data between devices today: https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/

Comment: @TiM I was looking for this question so I could modify my answer accordingly, but I couldn't find it, so thanks for the note